# How can I localize iOS app built in Flash for different languages?

Tags: ios, flash, actionscript-3, localization

I'm currently working on converting an Android app I built natively as an iPhone app.  I'm recreating it in Flash as I know AS3 but not Objective C.  My original Android app is localized for 4 different languages (it's so easy to do with Android!) - and my question is - how would I do this for the iOS version from Flash?  Would I be able to use separate XML files with all the strings in each language and load them in after somehow detecting which language the user's device is set to?

Many thanks!

*SOLUTION*

It was easy!  Thanks to crooksy88's link, I ended up using the following code:

```
var languageSettings:Array = Capabilities.languages;
var locale:String = languageSettings[0].toString().toLowerCase();
```

This gave me a 2-letter language code: 'en' for English, 'de' for German, etc. which I was able to use to load the correct xml file for each language.  Very simple in the end :)

Comment: Something is not right here! Flash for iOS? since when did iOS supported flash?!

Comment: You can use Flash 5.5 as a tool to make apps for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Didn't know that! And appstore would approve that? or this is just for entreprise distribution?

Comment: Totally fine with the Appstore!  And basically very very simple to do (until you run into problems like the above) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is iPhone specific but...

http://forums.adobe.com/message/4034939#4034939

Comment: That looks like it's just what I need.  Thank you - I'll try it out tonight!